# Choose maximum value special condition in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
customer_id    product_code    No_visits
1              90              15
1              105             30
1              100             45
2              50              60
2              100             45
2              10              30
```

I want to choose the customer_id, product_code corresponding with having the highest no_visits

```
customer_id    product_code    No_visits
1              100             45
2              50              60

df.groupby('customer_id')['product_code, no_visits'].max()
```

which gives me the results of maximum product_code and maximum no_visits, which are absolutely not what I want. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `idxmax` is for.  Grab the index of the maximum value then use that index in a call to `loc`.

This will produce identical results to MaxU but potentially different results as AmiTavory.  Ami's results may produce more than one result per `customer_id` if there is more than one row that has a `No_visits` value equal to the maximum value.  Mine and MaxU's answers will select whichever row came first and is equal to the max.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('customer_id').No_visits.idxmax()]

   customer_id  product_code  No_visits
2            1           100         45
3            2            50         60
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
>>> df[df.No_visits == df.No_visits.groupby(df.customer_id).transform(max)]

   customer_id  product_code  No_visits
2            1           100         45
3            2            50         60
```

**Explanation**

```
df.No_visits == df.No_visits.groupby(df.customer_id).transform(max)
```

finds, for each row, the maximal number of visits for the customer id of that row. Then you simply filter on the rows for those where the number of visits is equal to that number.

Comment: Thanks, @piRSquared!

Answer (score 2):

One more option:

```
In [93]: (df.groupby('customer_id', as_index=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1,'No_visits'))
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
Out[93]:
   customer_id  product_code  No_visits
2            1           100         45
3            2            50         60
```

or [much nicer option from @piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080152/choose-maximum-value-special-condition-in-pandas/50080797?noredirect=1#comment87184017_50080797):

```
In [49]: pd.concat((d.nlargest(1, 'No_visits') for _, d in df.groupby('customer_id')))
Out[49]:
   customer_id  product_code  No_visits
2            1           100         45
3            2            50         60
```

Comment: Alternative... same idea `pd.concat((d.nlargest(1, 'No_visits') for _, d in df.groupby('customer_id')))`

Comment: @piRSquared, yeah, it looks much cleaner - thank you! :)